# Are "wonder" and "wander" etymologically related?

Tags: etymology

Especially in lyric-writing, where used more figuratively than literally, *e.g. (mental) wandering* and *wondering*, the two seem often interchangeable. And I can see *wondering* being conceived as an analogue of *wandering* (only, in one's mind). However from peering at their etymologies (see: [wonder](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=wonder) and [wander](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=wander)), it appears this isn't the case—or have I simply not dug deep enough?

Comment: Not quite far enough, but they're still unrelated. _Wander_ comes from PIE _*wendh-_ 'to turn, wind, weave'; but _wonder_ appears to be a word limited to Germanic languages. Proto-Germanic had a lot of words that didn't come from PIE; nobody knows where they came from, but they thrived in Germanic languages.

Comment: @JohnLawler - Thank you. (If you'd copy your comment as an answer, I'd accept it immediately so as to mark this question as answered. I understand if you have your reasons for not doing so, however.)

Comment: More work, is all. Plus comments force me to be succinct. I'm practicing up for Twitter.

Comment: I don't have an answer, just a related comment: Given how modern languages (or at least my native language, U.S. English) often include "typos," when I discover possibly related words like wonder and wander, I often wonder [ ;-D ] if people many generations ago also made typos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two words have separate origins, although they may have crossed paths along the way.

[***Wonder***](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=wonder) comes from Old English ***wundrian,*** the verb form of *wundor* “marvelous thing, marvel, the object of astonishment,” from Proto-Germanic ****wundran*** (origin unknown). In Middle English, the noun became associated with the emotion of wonder (late 1200s), and the verb had a transitive sense meaning “to inspire curiosity in.”

[***Wander***](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=wander) comes from Old English ***wandrian*** “move about aimlessly, wander,” ultimately from Proto-Indo-European ****wend-*** “to turn.” It's related to the verbs *wind* and *wend.* This word also became associate with the mind, emotions, affections, etc., in Middle English (c.1400).

Thus, *wonder* comes from a uniquely Germanic noun, and *wander* comes from an Indo-European verb, but they both became associated with the mind in Middle English. It's quite common for similar-sounding words to influence each other through confusion and wordplay, so there may be some convergence – you certainly aren't the first person to notice a metaphorical similarity between the two.

Comment: I never thought of the idea of convergence due to similar sounds being confused in language as you describe but it makes a lot of sense. I imagined "wondering" could result and "wandering" at least metaphorically and both words have a similar indefiniteness if that makes sense.